# getting from histogram counts to cdf

Tags: r

I have a dataframe where I have values, and for each value I have the counts associated with that value. So, plotting counts against values gives me the histogram. I have three types, `a`, `b`, and `c`.

```
              value  counts     type
                   0 139648267  a
                   1  34945930  a
                   2   5396163  a
                   3   1400683  a
                   4    485924  a
                   5    204631  a
                   6     98599  a
                   7     53056  a
                   8     30929  a
                   9     19556  a
                  10     12873  a
                  11      8780  a
                  12      6200  a
                  13      4525  a
                  14      3267  a
                  15      2489  a
                  16      1943  a
                  17      1588  a
                 ...     ...   ...
```

How do I get from this to a CDF?

So far, my approach is super inefficient: I first write a function that sums up the counts up to that value:

```
get_cumulative <- function(x) {
  result <- numeric(nrow(x))
   for (i in seq_along(result)) {
   result[i] = sum(x[x$num_groups <= x$num_groups[i], ]$count)
  }
  x$cumulative <- result
  x
}
```

Then I wrap this in a `ddply` that splits by the type. This is obviously not the best way, and I'd love any suggestions on how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ave` and `cumsum` (assuming your data is in `df` and sorted by value):

```
transform(df, cdf=ave(counts, type, FUN=function(x) cumsum(x) / sum(x)))
```

Here is a toy example:

```
df <- data.frame(counts=sample(1:100, 10), type=rep(letters[1:2], each=5))
transform(df, cdf=ave(counts, type, FUN=function(x) cumsum(x) / sum(x)))
```

that produces:

```
   counts type       cdf
1      55    a 0.2750000
2      61    a 0.5800000
3      27    a 0.7150000
4      20    a 0.8150000
5      37    a 1.0000000
6      45    b 0.1836735
7      79    b 0.5061224
8      12    b 0.5551020
9      63    b 0.8122449
10     46    b 1.0000000
```

Comment: You're a life saver, I was doing an `expandRows`, and then using `ecdf`, but this is much better!

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in data.frame `DF` then following should do

`do.call(rbind, lapply(split(DF, DF$type), FUN=cumsum))`

Answer (score 0):

The [HistogramTools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HistogramTools) package on CRAN has several functions for converting between Histograms and CDFs, calculating information loss or error margins, and plotting functions to help with this.

If you have a histogram `h` then calculating the Empirical CDF of the underlying dataset is as simple as:

```
library(HistogramTools)
h <- hist(runif(100), plot=FALSE)
plot(HistToEcdf(h))
```

If you first need to convert your input data of breaks and counts into an R Histogram object, then see the `PreBinnedHistogram` function first.